# Why can I select multiple columns from dual?

Tags: oracle

When I execute this query:

```
select 2+2, 2+2, 2+2 from dual;
```

I get multiple columns but, as per definition, `dual` only has one row and one column. So what is the reason behind it?

Answer (score 5):

The number of columns in a table has nothing to do with the number of columns in the projection of a `SELECT` statement.  You can always add additional computed columns to the projection (at least practically...  theoretically, you might eventually hit some sort of logical limit).

The fact that you are querying `dual` here is irrelevant.  You can do exactly the same thing with any table.  The projection in this query

```
SELECT e.*, 2+2 computed_one, 2+3 computed_two, 2+4 computed_three
  FROM emp e
```

returns all the columns in the `emp` table along with three additional computed columns `computed_one`, `computed_two`, and `computed_three`.  The fact that `dual` always has exactly one row makes it useful when you want the result to have exactly one row but other than that, there is no logical difference whether you use `dual` or a single-row, single-column table that you create yourself.

Answer (score 0):

- DUAL is a table automatically created by Oracle Database along with
  the data dictionary.
- DUAL is in the schema of the user SYS but is accessible by the name
  DUAL to all users. It has one column, DUMMY, defined to be
  VARCHAR2(1), and contains one row with a value X.
- Selecting from the DUAL table is useful for computing a constant
  expression with the SELECT statement. Because DUAL has only one row,
  the constant is returned only once.
- Alternatively, you can select a constant, pseudocolumn, or expression
  from any table, but the value will be returned as many times as there
  are rows in the table.
- In Oracle you just can not write a SQL statement like,

  SELECT 2+2;
- Instead you have to write,

  SELECT 2+2 from dual;
- This is just the SQL convention standard for Oracle. This is
  different for all databases, like SQL Server uses,

  SELECT 2+2;

Hope you are cleared with this.